# Is there a way to set secure_auth to false in MySQLdb.connect in Python 2.7.5?

Tags: python, mysql

I am attempting to run a script written in Python 2.7.5 (not using Django). When it tries to connect to a remote mysql server with the MySQLdb.connect() method it throws the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2049, "Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)")
```

I have done reading about this issue:

- [Django/MySQL-python - Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023387/django-mysql-python-connection-using-old-pre-4-1-1-authentication-protocol-r)
- [mysql error 2049 connection using old (pre-4-1-1) authentication from mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239699/mysql-error-2049-connection-using-old-pre-4-1-1-authentication-from-mac)

Is there a way to set a parameter in the MySQLdb.connect() method to set `secure_auth` to false? Without having to change any passwords or running the command from the cmd line. I have looked at the [official docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) and there does not appear to be anything in there.

I have tried adding `secure_auth=False` to the parameters but throws an error (shown in the code below).

**Python:**

```
def get_cursor():
    global _cursor
    if _cursor is None:
        try:
            db = MySQLdb.connect(user=_usr, passwd=_pw, host='external.website.com', port=3306, db=_usr, charset="utf8")
            # tried this but it doesnt work (as expect but tried anyway) which throws this error
            # TypeError: 'secure_auth' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
            # db = MySQLdb.connect(user=_usr, passwd=_pw, host='external.website.com', port=3306, db=_usr, charset="utf8", secure_auth=false)
            _cursor = db.cursor()
        except MySQLdb.OperationalError:
            print "error connecting"
            raise
    return _cursor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent an inordinate amount of time working through the MySQLdb source code and determined that this simply cannot be done without patching the MySQLdb's C wrapping code. Theoretically, you should be able to pass the SECURE_CONNECTION flag to specify that do not want to use the insecure old passwords:

`MySQLdb.connect(..., client_flags=MySQLdb.constant.CLIENT.SECURE_CONNECTION)`

But the MySQLdb code never actually checks that flag, and never configures the secure_connection option when calling the MySQL connection code, so it always defaults to requiring new-style passwords.

Possible fixes include:

- Patch the MySQLdb code
- Use an old version of the MySQL client libraries
- Update the passwords on the MySQL server
- Create a single new user with a new-style password

Sorry I don't have a better answer. I just ran into this problem myself!

Comment: What you listed above is what I was fearing. Thank you for confirming that it cannot be done. It was helpful!

Comment: it looks like the C API has been patched but the issue is still ongoing for me using mysql-python, @niczero do you have a idea why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

I know Moses answer as been validated but I wanted to offer my work around based on what he suggested.

I had previously installed mysql_python for my python and had the brew version of mysql installed.

I deteleted all of that.

I look for a way to install MySQLdb by looking for it last stable version with the source.

I compiled them (followed the isntructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x)), installed them and then I looked for a stable version of MySQL client (MySQL website is the best place for that) and install the 5.5 version which was perfectly fitting my requirements.

I made mysql to launch itself automatically and then restarted my computer (but you can just restart apache) and check that all path were correct and the right includes are in the right places (you can check that against the link above).

And now it all works fine!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is a separate paramter that you can set in the connection paramter...Here is a note from the source code...Try checking mysql_ssl_set() documentation.

```
 ssl
          dictionary or mapping, contains SSL connection parameters;
          see the MySQL documentation for more details
          (mysql_ssl_set()).  If this is set, and the client does not
          support SSL, NotSupportedError will be raised.
```

This document talks about all the secure parameters - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-ssl-set.html...

I don't see anything to disable secure auth in glance..